# HTML phone drop down inconsistency

Tags: html, css, mobile, drop-down-menu

So I have code to create a drop down that is used for my website aimed at mobile users. However it works on one page but not another.

*What other code could be interfering for this problem to occur?*

**It works here:**

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#page-top">Fortune Filly</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="hidden">
                        <a href="#page-top"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page-scroll">
                        <a href="#portfolio">Memberships</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page-scroll">
                        <a href="#about">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page-scroll">
                        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page-scroll">
                        <a href="loginTemplate.php">Login</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
```

**But not here:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">

        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Fortune Filly </a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="hidden">
                        <a href="#page-top"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page-scroll">
                        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page-scroll">
                        <a href="accountDetails.php">Account Details</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page-scroll">
                        <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

I will add that on the page that it **isn't** working I am getting the error: session_start() Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent

Here is the rest of the code for the page which doesn't work:

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
session_start();
ob_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    header("location:http://www.fortunefilly.com/loginTemplate.php");
}
else
{
    $username =$_SESSION['username'];
    $check = $mysqli->query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
    $row = $check->fetch_assoc();
    $id = $row['id'];
}
?>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Fortune Filly</title>

    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/freelancer.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>
<body id="page-top" class="index">

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">

            <div class="container">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Fortune Filly </a>
                </div>

                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="hidden">
                            <a href="#page-top"></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="index.html">Home</a>

                        <li>
                            <a href="accountDetails.php">Account Details</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>

<section class="success" id="about">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <br>
                    <h2>Welcome <?php echo $username;?></h2>
                    <hr class="star-light">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-2">
                    <p>To gain access to the members section and receive daily horse racing tips from our professionals <a href='userPage.php'>Click here</a></p>   

                    <?php
                    $check = $mysqli->query("SELECT is_member FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
                    $row = $check->fetch_assoc();
                    $isMember = $row['is_member'];
                    if ($isMember == 0){
                    echo'<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="CTKLZLJZBA4P4">
<table>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value=""></td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0">
    <option value="Weekly">Weekly : £5.00 GBP - weekly</option>
    <option value="Monthly">Monthly : £15.00 GBP - monthly</option>
    <option value="Yearly">Yearly : £60.00 GBP - yearly</option>
</select> </td></tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="$id">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
<input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/GB/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online.">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>


                    ';
                    // echo '<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
                    // <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
                    // <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="$id">
                    // <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="H4K679J6Y5T7C">
                    // <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/GB/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online.">
                    // <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
                    // </form>';
                    }
                    ?>


                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what code? and what dropdown? The html is kinda useless without the related JS/CSS.

Comment: Surely you wouldn't need to see it if it works for one? @MarcB

Comment: They both work fine for me. First: http://www.bootply.com/render/ZIoghuCYUx Second: http://www.bootply.com/render/zuqucHeXGV

Comment: @APAD1 So is there something which could possibly be interfering?

Comment: I don't know, but what you've posted works fine, so if there is an issue, it's in code that you haven't posted.

Comment: @APAD1 I uploaded the rest of the html file, in the edit

Comment: Adding an answer based on what I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so based on the latest code you posted, I believe this is your issue. On the login page, there is a bit of jQuery at the bottom of the page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    LoginModalController.initialize();
});
```

However, it seems like jQuery is either not loading properly or it's being loaded after the function is fired because I'm getting:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

It also looks like you're not loading `bootstrap.min.js` on the login page which, I believe, is required for the nav dropdown(not entirely sure though as I've never used that feature of Bootstrap).

**UPDATE:** OP was calling the `login.js` file in the header and footer, the one being called in the header was causing a reference error as it was firing before jQuery was loaded.

Comment: You have confused me far more than I originally was :O

Comment: Surely it wouldn't be anything to do with the jquery or javascript as the homepage is proof it works

Comment: It's definitely an issue with the jQuery or Javascript, the reason it's working on the homepage is because you have it coded one way on the homepage and a completely different way on the login page. I would recommend making a single header and a single footer. Then load `jQuery`, `Bootstrap` and `FontAwesome` in the header file and include that file on your other pages. It will be much cleaner and easier to maintain. Currently you're loading a local version of jQuery 1.11.1 on the homepage and then on the login page you're loading a remote CDN version of jQuery 2.1.3, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: I used a template for the homepage and a seperate one for the login page so all the jQuery and javascript is pretty much over my head at the moment, I'm unsure how to implement what you just commented

Comment: Alright, I see the exact problem now. On the login page, you are loading the file `login.js` twice. Once in the header and the other one in the footer, but jQuery is only being loaded in the footer. So basically the `$(document).ready` function from the header `login.js` is firing before jQuery is loading, which prevents any Javascript on the page from work. Clean up your code and it will work.

Comment: So should i get rid of the one in the header?

Comment: or should I put the jQuery in the header?

Comment: Get rid of the `login.js` in the header and it might work. However, as I said before, you might also need to load `bootstrap.min.js` on that page(it's not currently). Also, I would still recommend cleaning up your code because you're bound to run into more problems if you don't.

Comment: Okay, so adding the bootstrap.min.js at the bottom of the code did the trick. You are a beautiful human being!